# Seeking a plot of the energy history of the Universe

Tags: energy, cosmology, space-expansion, universe, density

How can we plot the energy density $\rho$ as a function of the age $t$ of the universe (or temperature $T$) from the time of radiation domination to the time of cosmological constant domination with intermediate matter domination phase? I know that $$a\propto t^{1/2}, t^{2/3}, e^{\Lambda t}$$ in the radiation, matter, and CC dominated phases respectively. Therefore, $$\rho\propto t^{-2}, {\rm constant}$$ for radiation/matter domination and CC domination respectively. In short, I am looking for a continuous curve $\rho(t)$ vs $t$. Can we identify the crossover from radiation to matter domination in this curve?

Comment: A complete history means that there are eras when the universe is *not* dominated by one of these, and the scale factor therefore does *not* evolve as you say. You can integrate the Friedmann equations taking into account all three contributions to get the curve you want, and the curve of each contribution, including their crossover points. I didn’t manage to find a graph of the total on the internet. I found two graphs of the three separate contributions but they were inconsistent with each other.

Comment: https://pages.uoregon.edu/jimbrau/BrauImNew/Chap27/7th/AT_7e_Figure_27_01.jpg

Comment: https://sites.ualberta.ca/~pogosyan/teaching/ASTRO_122/lect30a/lecture30a.html

Comment: Note that both are log-log plots but in one the radiation and matter curves bend up and in the other they bend down. I haven’t tried the integration myself so I don’t know which is correct. Note that if the time dependence were $t^{-2}$ the two curves would be straight lines.

Comment: It’s possible that they disagree because one of them takes into account how the radiation interacts with the matter, rather than considering a simple noninteracting [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Mixtures). I don’t understand how this interaction is usually modeled in cosmological computations.

Comment: It is not easy to plot $\rho$ vs $t$. You can make approximations to obtain $a(t)$ and then plot it but then it is not easy. You can plot $\rho$ vs $a$

Comment: @G. Smith - The oregon plot is wrong while the alberta plot is correct, maybe they drew the first one by hand after setting to few sample points but the curves for radiation and matter must bend down on a logarithmic ρ(t) plot, see http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/y#r2 - the mixture is no longer relevant in late times, where the discrepancy between the two plots occurs, so the first one is really wrong.

Comment: @seVenVo1d - you can plot by t, the relation between t and a is simply t(a)=∫{0...a}[dã/ã/H(ã)] since da/dt=ȧ=H·a, so you have to do it numerically if you have a mixed component universe where radiation can't be neglected, but that's what computers are for (there are [analytical solutions](http://yukterez.rf.gd/f/einstein.equations/files/d) for that as well, but they are longer to type in than to perform the numerical integral)

Answer (score 0):

> Solidification asked: *"How can we plot the energy density ρ as a function of the age t of the universe (or temperature T) from the time of radiation domination to the time of cosmological constant domination with intermediate matter domination phase?"*

For the Ω I recommend a log/linear plot where the time (on the x-axis) is logartihmic and the Ω (on the y-axis) are linear. Red is for radiation, blue for matter and green for dark energy:

[image: Omega by time]

We have radiation to matter parity at 50000 years after the big bang, radiation to dark energy parity at 600 million years, and matter to dark energy parity at 10¹⁰ years. ρ (in GeV/c²/m³):

[image]

The accelerated expansion however does not start when Ω or ρ for dark energy becomes the largest, but when ä=0, which is at around 7.7 billion years (this plot is linear on both axes):

[image]

If you click on the images you get different combinations of logarithmic and linear axes and plot ranges, where different features are highlighted. The equations are also linked in the description on the bottom of the first two links, where you can also find the initial values for the cosmological parameters.